# Still Get Reminder Messages Re Security Patch

Tags: magento-1.7, security, patches

I think the patches for the latest security issue with Magento has been installed, but I keep getting messages in the Admin area saying it is critical that I install the patches.

Is this a standard message, or is the message only sent to the Magento stores who have not yet installed the patch?

I would like to know, as I asked the host to do it... Maybe they didn't?

Comment: test your store with the following: https://shoplift.byte.nl/

Comment: It's only a flood message sent out because somebody published the fact that Magento has a hole. Mag-E-Bay didn't have the courtesy to send notifications on either patch back in October 2014 or February 2015 when they were released. Hmm... My notification on 5344 was through this website because somebody noticed 6 days after its release and asked about it here.

Answer (score 4):

You can click the link Go to messages inbox in the top right corner and then click mark as read, and the reminders will be gone